# Why do I get a segmentation fault with this char?

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault

So I'm starting to learn C, tried to make a little program to learn about structures. It asks two "players" to enter their name and age, and then displays it back.

When I run it, I get a segmentation fault after entering the second player's last name. I don't get why.

I tried to run it in `gdb` and got the following message :

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7e5288c in _IO_vfscanf () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

Here is my code, `struct.c` :

```
#include "struct.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  Person player[1];
  int i = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    printf("\n=== Player %d ===\n", i+1);
    printf("First name : ");
    scanf("%s", player[i].firstName);
    printf("Last name : ");
    scanf("%s", player[i].lastName);
    printf("Age : ");
    scanf("%d", &player[i].age);
  }

  for (i = 0 ; i < 2; i++) {
    printf("\n=== Player %d ===\n", i+1);
    printf("%s %s, %d years old", player[i].firstName, player[i].lastName, player[i].age);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

And here is the header, `struct.h` :

```
#ifndef DEF_STRUCT
#define DEF_STRUCT
#define CHAR_SIZE 100

typedef struct Person Person;
struct Person {
  char firstName[CHAR_SIZE];
  char lastName[CHAR_SIZE];
  int age; 
};

#endif
```

Thanks!

Comment: And what warnings did you compiler emit when you compile your code?  Read them...

Comment: `Person player[1];` generates an array with size for `1` element.

Comment: `Person player[1]` -> `Person player[2]`

Comment: *Never* use `scanf("%s", ...);` without restricting the input length. `scanf("%99s", ...);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like people told me in the comments, I replaced `Person player[1]` by `Person player[2]`.

It now works.

Comment: I hope you understand _why_ you needed to do this.

Comment: To make the array long enough to have enough allocated memory, right?